# Rotation transformation of labels on x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello I have this visual: https://plnkr.co/edit/H6M1xoS9cZv5dKCTIyid?p=preview

I'm attempting to rotate the labels of the x-axis and have tried amending the code in lines 299-317 to no avail - so I feel code such as `.attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );` needs adding to the following?

```
// Add x labels to chart
var xLabels = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height) + ")");

xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
  .data(BarData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.dt;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return (i * (width / BarData.length)) + ((width / BarData.length - barPadding) / 2);
  })
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using the `.attr("x"` to position the axis text.  You should be using translate to do this otherwise your rotation will rotate all the elements from the bottom left.

the code should look like this, the translate and the rotation should occur within the same transform function:

```
.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return "translate("
      + ((i * (width / BarData.length)) + ((width / BarData.length - barPadding) / 2))
      + ", 0) rotate(-65)";
})
```

Here is a working version of your plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/UqwtLqTn6iJ2XS012Vr4?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: appreciated your help - compared to creating a chart in say excel, D3 is like a swiss watch ... beautiful but every component needs pain-staking attention!

Answer (score 0):

With links help I eventually used the following code:

```
xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
  .data(BarData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.dt;
  })
  .attr({
    'text-anchor': "middle",
    transform: function(d, i) {
      var x = (i * (width / BarData.length)) + ((width / BarData.length - barPadding) / 2);
      var y = 20;
      return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')rotate(-90)';
    },
    dy: "0.35em",
    'class': "xAxis"
  })
```

Working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/3d5UhM?p=preview

I also added in the attribute `dy: "0.35em"` to fully centre the labels to each bar.